# Android app - using AsyncTask - stops opening a URL in WebView, it is opened by the default browser if I call another URL

Tags: browser, android-asynctask, android-webview

I'm beginning to develop in android using the material from http://developer.android.com.

I took one of their examples and modified it, so that my application can connect to a webpage. It works well when it is opened but if I click on an actionBar item which should open another page the new page isn't opened in the WebView, but it's launched the default browser.

I tried in many way to understand how to avoid that, but my little experience didn't allow me to fixe the problem.

Can you help me?

Many thanks.
Nino

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String WIFI = "Wi-Fi";
    public static final String ANY = "Any";
    public static String PAGINA ="http://www.kibao.org/simu/wap.php?lng=";    
    public static String BASE ="http://www.kibao.org";
    public static String ATTUALE ="";
    public static String lng = "";
    final Context context = this;

    private static boolean wifiConnected = false;
    private static boolean mobileConnected = false;
    public static boolean refreshDisplay = true;
    public static String sPref = null;

    public static String pagina = "";

    private NetworkReceiver receiver = new NetworkReceiver();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        lng = getResources().getString(R.string.lng);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        receiver = new NetworkReceiver();
        this.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        sPref = sharedPrefs.getString("listPref", "Wi-Fi");

        updateConnectedFlags();


        if (refreshDisplay) {
            ATTUALE=PAGINA.concat(lng);
            loadPage(ATTUALE);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onStop();
        String ciao = getResources().getString(R.string.ciao);
        show_toast(ciao);
        if (receiver != null) {
           this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        }
    }
    private void updateConnectedFlags() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeInfo != null && activeInfo.isConnected()) {
            wifiConnected = activeInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
            mobileConnected = activeInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;
        } else {
            wifiConnected = false;
            mobileConnected = false;
        }
    }

    private void loadPage(String pgUrl) {
        if (((sPref.equals(ANY)) && (wifiConnected || mobileConnected))
            || ((sPref.equals(WIFI)) && (wifiConnected))) {
            new DownloadWebpageTask().execute(pgUrl);
        } else {
            showErrorPage();
        }
    }

   // Displays an error if the app is unable to load content.
   private void showErrorPage() {
        .... 
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.items, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu1:
        if (refreshDisplay) {

            ATTUALE=BASE.concat("/partite.php?lng=");
            ATTUALE=ATTUALE.concat(lng);
            loadPage(ATTUALE);
        }
        return true;
    ....
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    }
    private InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
        return stream;
   }

    public class NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           ConnectivityManager connMgr =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (WIFI.equals(sPref) && networkInfo != null
                && networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                refreshDisplay = true;
                Toast.makeText(context, R.string.wifi_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (ANY.equals(sPref) && networkInfo != null) {
                refreshDisplay = true;
            } else {
                refreshDisplay = false;
                Toast.makeText(context, R.string.lost_connection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
            return loadWebpageFromNetwork(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return getResources().getString(R.string.connection_error);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            myWebView.loadUrl(ATTUALE);            
        }
    }
    private String loadWebpageFromNetwork(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        try {
            stream = downloadUrl(urlString);
            pagina = getStringFromInputStream(stream);
        } finally {
            if (stream != null) {
                stream.close();
            }
        }
    return pagina;
    }
    private static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();

}        
........
}
```

Comment: This DownloadWebpageTask tries to "download" a webpage into a string, using a webview. Is that what you want to do, download a webpage? Or do you just want to show it to a user?

Comment: Thanks Frank for your help. I would make the user get the webpage as by a browser, but by the app and not the browser. The code works fine at starting, but when I click on an item of the actionbar which should open another page the default browser is launched. I don't want that.

Comment: I've noticed that the problem shows up when the called page redirects to a login page. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This DownloadWebpageTask tries to "download" a webpage into a string, using a webview. This is not the correct way to do it. You are using the wrong tutorial. Don't use AsyncTasks for this. Start all over, using this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

or

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

Simply call webview.loadUrl(url) again with a different url if you want to load a different page. It's as simple as that.

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            myWebView.loadUrl(ATTUALE);            
    }
            WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);            
            myWebView.lo

Answer (score 0):

I've found another solution that works. I added the line

```
 myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

in the onPostExecute:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl(ATTUALE);            
}
```

Thanks, Frank.

PS I've tried to add a comment to the last Frank's post, but I didn't  succeed!

Comment: Okay, you are doing it in a far too complex way, but good luck.